# Can create directories but can't upload files

Tags: files, 9, iis

When I try to upload a file with a file field, Drupal creates a sites/default/files/2023-10 directory, but can't upload the file.  I see this validation error in the UI: "File upload error. Could not move uploaded file."  And I see a similar notice in the Drupal log: "Upload error. Could not move uploaded file test.txt to destination public://2023-10/test.txt."

In admin/config/media/file-system, my public file system path is set to sites/default/files.  There are no errors on the status page indicating a permissions problem.

If I delete the files directory altogether, and then save the form at admin/config/media/file-system, Drupal creates sites/default/files and sites/default/files/php.

What are the possible reasons Drupal can create directories inside of sites/default/files, but can't upload files?

```
Drupal version: 9.5.11
Web server: IIS 10
PHP 8.1.21
```

Comment: Is there any specific error you are getting while upload files in the logs either in console, try to upload file of smaller size like 2MB may be issue of file size larger

Comment: A possible reason is that whatever user context IIS or Drupal is running in can create directories but not files. I don't think we can give a fact-based acceptable answer without information from you as to what the filesystem permissions actually are.

Comment: @mini  The file size isn't the issue.  I updated the ticket with the  notice I'm seeing in the log, though it is similar to the validation error displayed in the UI.

Comment: @ciefen  I'm inexperienced with IIS permissions, but if Drupal is creating the files directory, shouldn't it do so in a way that does not require subsequent manual adjustment of that directory's permissions, or directories therein?  Prior to Drupal creating the files directory, I made IUSR a user of sites/default, and gave that user full permissions.

Comment: Please be aware of https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3358248

Comment: For testing purpose to be sure issue is folder permission related or not , try to change specific folder(2023-10) permission only to 777  then try to upload again file 
Be careful while trying this step.

Comment: Windows filesystem has no concept of 777 AFAIK.

Comment: It's a government project, and unfortunately, for bureaucratic reasons, it absolutely has to be on Windows/IIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to set the upload_tmp_dir in PHP.ini.  This is what worked for me:

upload_tmp_dir = c:\PHP\tmp

I also gave full permissions to the IUSR user for that directory.